# wsimport (xjc) - why list getter has always null check?

Tags: java, xjc, wsimport

I'm wondering why generated (from xsd) getter for list has always null check:

```js
public class Response {

    @XmlElement(type = Integer.class)
    protected List<Integer> integers;

    public List<Integer> getIntegers() {
        if (integers == null) {
            integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        return this.integers;
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Why? What is the reason? Is there any good one?

I'm asking becouse in some cases this is not a good thing. And looks like there is no way to change this behavior.

Comment: "I'm asking becouse in some cases this is not a good thing" Mind explaining this?

Comment: @Josh M, for example now I'm using Dozer to merge objects of the same type. Source object has null lists, but after calling getters lists are initialized. So source object has empty lists and therefore target object has empty lists. I have complex structure and I don't want to have initialized empty lists. Source object is changed and it shouldn't be changed. And since there is no way to change this way of generating getters I assume there is a really good reason to generate getters this way. Back to my question: what is that reason?

Comment: I assume this is a really stupid question, since I get downvotes. Looks like only I don't know why generator works this way. Nice.

Comment: Well, I mean, what do you hope to achieve by understanding this particular semantic? The concept shown in the snippet is called "lazy initialization" which, in short, means that it only gets initialized wherever it's required. The developer could have done this for any number of reasons, so we don't really know.

Comment: @Josh M, I'm understand semantic. But I don't know why generator generates getters this way. Why there is no simple way to customize that, and have standard getters and setters? I really would like to know if there is any concept or reason for that. Maybe there is no reason at all, and simply that how it works and thats all.

Comment: Suppose you had 1000 different fields (all uninitialized) with 1000 different getters which used lazy initialization. Now suppose you only used 2 of those get methods. If you were to initialize all 1000 fields in the constructor, why would you want to allocate memory for the other 998 (unused) fields?

Comment: @Josh M, why should I initialize all lists in constructor? I assume that would be necessary when lists need to be initialized. But this isn't always true. Lists could be null, and that will be ok in some cases. For example in mine.

Comment: I think the reason is because in nearly all cases where a getter returns a List, the first thing the caller does with it is iterate over it or add something to it.  In both of those cases, immediate NullPointerExceptions would occur, unless the calling code explicitly checks for null, which forces the calling code to know more about the internals of your object than good design would suggest it should.  The calling code becomes more tightly coupled to yours.

Comment: @Ian McLaird, I agree that in most cases List is iterated. But "lazy initialization" is not a magic solution. I think that when writing code that works with lists it is a good habit to check nulls. Simply becouse not all getters initialize lists. This is not a standard, and you cannot force everyone to do that. But when working with objects generated from wsdl(xsd) it is true, getters always return list. But sometimes (for example me) this is not a wanted behavior. And generated code could be mine or clients code (depends who generates). If the code is generated by client it is a part of his..

Comment: @Ian McLaird, ... application. So we cannot talk about good design or bad design.

Comment: What, in your application, is the semantic difference between an empty list and a null one?  *Why* is an empty list bad or different from a null one?  Avoiding null is generally a good idea (not *just* with lists) whenever you can do it.  See https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained

Comment: You'll also note that xjc doesn't generate setters for lists at all, which has its own implications.

Comment: @Ian McLaird, why this makes difference for me is explained in my first comment in this discussion. I know that setter is not generated. There is no need to have setter when list is initialized. But this makes not possible to replace current list with a new one. Maybe this was some kind of requirement some time ago?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a bit of digging, the reason becomes clear.  I generated some code with `xjc` and for a list property, it created this comment:

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the bars property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the bars property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getBars().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link Bar }
 * 
 * 
 */
```

This makes their intent clear.  They wanted it to be impossible to have a stale `List` from the object, so it always returns the live list rather than making a copy.  This means that multiple calls to the getter (from different threads or different contexts, for example), will always be given references to the same in-memory object.  Doing this, however, meant that they couldn't have a setter, or they'd break this contract -- Context A could set the value, and Context B would then have a stale reference to the old value, and have no way to know that it had been changed.

Since, because of that design decision, they couldn't have a setter, there needed to be some way to mutate the list if you needed to add or remove items. Otherwise, an initially `null` list would always be `null` forever (barring shenanigans with reflection).  Thus, the only remaining way to allow that was to check for `null` in the getter, and lazy-initialize at that time.  That meant that the scheme for replacing the entire list had to be

```
foo.getBars().clear();
foo.getBars().addAll(someList);
```

As for *why* they chose this design...there's no way for anybody outside that team to know the answer to that.  However, it's generally a very good pattern to follow for most code anyway (it reduces coupling, and eliminates common error conditions that the compiler can't warn you about), so it's hard to make much of an argument against it.  If it's really causing you trouble (and you haven't really shown how it is, other than the fact that some of your objects have empty lists after a copy operation instead of null ones), then the only advice I can give you is to either not use the code generator, or write an extension for `xjc` to make it do what you want.  There may even be an existing extension for this.  I don't know.

Comment: This is a good answer, so I think it can be accepted. Thanks for your effort. Have a nice day.